# How to split string with multiple delimiters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string:

```
var str = '15/17/*18/20/*22';
```

How can I split it so executing the following line:

```
var results = str.split(REGEX);
```

Will end up giving the following results:

```
result = ['/','/*','/','/*'];
```

Thank you!

Comment: `var results = str.split(/\d+/);`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no attempt was made to do something so basic.

Comment: It almost works perfectly, it give an empty cells at the beginning and end of result array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `split` like this:

```
var str = '15/17/*18/20/*22';
var m = str.split(/\d+/).filter(Boolean);
//=> ["/", "/*", "/", "/*"]
```

Or else (thanks to @hwnd):

```
var m = str.split(/[^/*]+/).filter(Boolean);
```

Comment: You don't need the `g` modifier =)

Comment: Yes took that out thanks !

Comment: Just looking out. (`+1`)

Comment: adding filter(Boolean) gets the right results!

Answer (score 0):

code

```
x = '15/17/*18/20/*22'
x.split(/[0-9][0-9]*/)
```

result

```
["", "/", "/*", "/", "/*", ""]
```